# How to make phone vibrate by thread while locked?

Tags: java, android, locking, screen, vibration

Whether the user has the screen on or off I want to notify the user by a vibration. If the screen is on, this works well:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            long sleep = 100;
                            long vibrate = 500;
                            long[] vibratePattern = {0, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep};
                            vibrator.vibrate(vibratePattern, -1);
```

Its called by a Thread that is implemented in a `Service`.

The Thread runs always even if the screen is off over hours if necessary. I checked that because im implementing a timer. So that cant be the problem!